# Rules are only applied from the last override?

Tags: angular, eslint, eslintrc

I have multiple `overrides` that target different file subsets, but some overlap.
But eslint only seems to use the last matched override, thereby ignoring some of my rules.

I have the following config:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "overrides": [
    ...
    {
      "files": [
        "**/app/**/*.ts"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
          "patterns": [{
            "group": ["*/platform-browser"],
            "message": "Bar"
          }]
        }]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "**/src/**/*.ts"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
          "patterns": [{
            "group": ["*/core"],
            "message": "Foo"
          }]
        }]
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Then I have the file `src\app\app.module.ts`:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; //<-- Should trigger Foo
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; //<-- Should trigger Bar

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But it only triggers one of the rules (the one that's last in the override array)

Is there someway to apply both?

I have a sample repository [here](https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/eslint-issue) if that helps

Comment: ESLint overrides merge only for files. Rules can't merge and it seems reasonable as otherwise you wouldn't be able to make a complete override of a rule

Answer (score 0):

If your app and source are one directory deep you could try `*/src/**/*.ts` to make a clear distinction between the two.

You should also change the order because every src has an app, not every app has a source so you want src to be first and app to be last to override src.

I hope that fixes the issue. I don't know the exact ins and outs so I can't help you further.

Comment: Hi this is just a dummy example that doesn't 100% reflect the real structure of my project where i need to apply this. but if I have understood eslint correctly it seems to only use the last type of each rule it finds, and I haven't found any way around that..

Answer (score 0):

According to the ESLint documentation, rules are applied from the last override in the array:

"If multiple rules are matched by different overrides, the last matching rule in the array will be used."

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy

Therefore, in your example, only the "no-restricted-imports" rule from the last override will be applied.

To fix this, you can move the "no-restricted-imports" rule from the second override to the first override, so that it will be applied last:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "overrides": [
    ...
    {
      "files": [
        "**/app/**/*.ts"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
          "patterns": [{
            "group": ["*/platform-browser"],
            "message": "Bar"
          }]
        }]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "**/src/**/*.ts"
      ],
      "rules": {
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Or, you can move the "no-restricted-imports" rule from the second override to a new override that targets both "**/app/**/*.ts" and "**/src/**/*.ts":

```
{
  "root": true,
  "overrides": [
    ...
    {
      "files": [
        "**/app/**/*.ts",
        "**/src/**/*.ts"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
          "patterns": [{
            "group": ["*/platform-browser"],
            "message": "Bar"
          }, {
            "group": ["*/core"],
            "message": "Foo"
          }]
        }]
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```